# Laravel4 + AngularJS. How to secure different routes in backend?

Tags: angularjs, laravel, backend

I have a web site based on Larvel 4 framework. And i want to replace current backend with dynamic one, based on AngularJS. Bu i don't understand how to secure different backend routes.
Now i have in my routes.php:

```
        Route::group(array('before' => 'manager-auth', 'prefix' => 'admin'), function()
    {

        // order management
        Route::group(array('prefix' => 'orders'), function()
        {
// Here order routes
        });

        // news management
        Route::group(array('prefix' => 'news'), function()
        {
// Here news routes
        });

        // all admin functions, no managers here!
        Route::group(array('before' => 'admin-auth'), function()
        {

            // user management
            Route::group(array('prefix' => 'users'), function()
            {
// Here user routes
            });

            // group management
            Route::group(array('prefix' => 'groups'), function()
            {
// Here group routes
            });

            // page management
            Route::group(array('prefix' => 'pages'), function()
            {
// Here page routes
            });
        });

        // dashboard
        Route::get('/', array('as' => 'admin', 'uses' => 'Controllers\Admin\DashboardController@getIndex'));
    });
```

So anybody from manager or admin group can administer news or orders and view dashboard, but only members of admin group can manage users, groups and pages.

If i understand correctly, the best way to rewrite backend in AngularJS is to use html templates, angular routing and ng-view directive. Laravel in this scenario is only for serving json, validating input and for logging in users.

But how can i implement different secure areas for admins and for managers?
Do i need to create Laravel controller and route just for client-side checks for user permissions to do something? Or is there a better way to achieve this functionality?

And is it ok to put backend angular html templates to /public directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The laravel security/routes remain largely the same, but instead of rendering html it's going to return json files.

Both ngRoute and [angular-ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) have a `resolve` property which allows you to reject users that aren't allowed to go to a certain route.
But there are multiple ways to solve the routing:

- http://arthur.gonigberg.com/2013/06/29/angularjs-role-based-auth/
- http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/deal-with-users-authentication-in-an-angularjs-web-app
- [etc](https://www.google.com/search?q=angularjs+authentication+routes)

Putting backend templates in a public location does give hackers insight into the backend frontend code and *could* expose an XSS attack surface, but AngularJS >= 1.2 [makes it hard](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24sce) to inject html into your views.

I've used a strategy where the templates where in a "protected/" folder which could only be accessed by logged in users.

If you already using [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) I suggest checking out [grunt-angular-templates](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-angular-templates)
This allows you to group templates into a single javascript file.
So you'll only need 1 protected laravel route.

Comment: Thank you, it much clearer for me now. But there are some questions remain:    1. how to make /protected folder? I understand, that it need to be located in /public folder, but how can i protect it from specific users?    2. If i understand clearly, i need to make laravel controller for checking user group and call it from angular frontend, to make sure that user has specific rights to access this route, because angular scripts can be compromised. Am i right?

Comment: 1. Place the contents of the protected outside the public folder and access them via laravel routes. 2. Yep. A backend should always revalidate.